# How can I pass external json data to a macro in nunjucks?

Tags: json, macros, nunjucks

I've got a nunjucks macro for rendering a HTML input component. It works fine when called like this, with the JSON inline in the macro call:

```
{{ textfield_macro.textfield('search', fragmentdata = {"fieldname": "my_fieldname", "label": "The field label", "help": "For example 1212-2222-3333-4444"} ] }) }}
```

But I want the json data to be called in from another file. I've tried this:

```
{% set templateData %}
  {% include 'content/data/index.json' %}
{% endset %}

{{ textfield_macro.textfield('search', fragmentdata = templateData | safe ) }}
```

and that passes in the contents of index.json, but it's only available as a string in the macro, not a JSON object. I get the feeling I'm missing something very obvious, any help much appreciated!

Comment: Not completely solved this but just for anybody reading this, I've done a workaround using a custom filter to convert the data back to json. So: `{{ textfield_macro.textfield('search', fragmentdata = (templateData | tojson )) }}`